# Is armadillo C++ matrix thread safe

Tags: c++, armadillo

Armadillo is a C++ linear algebra library. I wonder if its implementation is thread safe? For example, I have a matrix A, and there are 2 threads modifying it. I looked at its documentation but this is not mentioned.

Comment: For all C++ libraries... if it isn't mentioned, it's probably not thread safe.

Comment: Related: [Is armadillo solve() thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063240/is-armadillo-solve-thread-safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely assume that everything is not thread-safe by default, unless stated otherwise.

This is because thread-safety adds overhead (locking) that would penalize single-threaded usage for no good reason. E.g. you can use a matrix in a multi-threaded application without ever sharing it with other threads.